# Install Ubuntu with windows 2000 without partitioning the hard drive

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows

I Really Need Help!
I Have Windows 2000. But it cannot start due to this error:

```
Windows could not start because the following file is missing or 
corrupt:\WINNT\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\SYSTEMced
```

I do not have a repair disk or anything to fix it, because it does not boot. I can not partition the hard drive so here is my question, Can I install Ubuntu on the same hard drive as 2000? I desperately need to get all my items off of Windows, yet remain able to boot to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will no be able to install Ubuntu with Wubi when Windows is unable to boot. The Wubi installer is an .exe that needs to be run from a properly booted Windows.

But what you can do is to start Ubuntu from the CD choosing the option **"Try out Ubuntu"**. This will boot your computer into a fully functional operating system. You can browse the internet, download files (e.g. a Windows repair CD), and you have full access to your hard drive in order to backup you personal data.

You can not however fix errors from your FAT32 or NTFS file-system. You would need to at least boot a minimal [Windows repair disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc) to have access to [`chkdsk`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457122%28TechNet.10%29.aspx) command.

Comment: Thank You So Much Dude. I got the iso mounted it to a cd. booted the try ubuntu and i got all of my stuff back it took a little while to get used to it.But all is good now. thank you =) You Can't Believe how happy i am.

Comment: Good you have sorted it out - I know how you feel, we all have been at that point somewhen ;)